# How to add an email signature when forwording an email in C Panel

Tags: email, cpanel, forward

Hi I want to improve my Email Forwarding service. Currently, it uses cPanel email forwarders. However I wish to use a PHP pipe instead, that adds a small notice to the end of the forwarded email, like ‘Forwarded from original@email.com

I wish to add the option to have a dynamic message at the end of the email that is being forwarded, like for example “This email is forwarded from test@forwarder.email. Click [HERE] to stop the forwarding.”  I did some research, and cPanel supports forwarding an email to a pipe, which means we can execute some PHP script when an email is received.
From the PHP, your goal is to tell cPanel to forward the email with this additional message.

Please note that the original "from" and "to" email address should still be shown in the email details, like currently (see attachment for example).